# cargo test fails when linking with cc

Tags: rust, ld, rust-cargo

I'm trying to run `cargo test` on my project, but it fails with this error

```
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /build/target/debug/deps/mylib_lua-02c930e07cd69371.2048jn2y48h28kbm.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /build/target/debug/deps/mylib_lua-02c930e07cd69371.26dkx5s8alo6obzk.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /build/target/debug/deps/mylib_lua-02c930e07cd69371.2nzhb579ueq0lzmq.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /build/target/debug/deps/mylib_lua-02c930e07cd69371.5g4hea07176h2p45.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Suprisingly, both `cargo build` and `cargo build --release` works for the same project.

What should I do to debug this failure? `cargo test --verbose` doesn't help much. Process returns `101` exit code and this error is produced

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
```

Comment: Edit your question to include your `Cargo.toml` please

Comment: Probably some dev-dependency somewhere in the graph. Are you running `cargo test` directly from the shell or are you using an IDE? An IDE "helpfully" adding features on test might look like this too.

Answer (score 0):

try again and test will be on the project
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /build/target/debug/deps/mylib_lua-02c930e07cd69371.2048jn2y48h28kbm.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
I Had that error also

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).